# Filter in ng-repeat is breaking selectable options in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a table that displays selectable information. There are parent rows and child rows.

I want the parent rows to be selectable if they have no children, otherwise only the child rows should be selectable. This is a select-only-one type of table.

I have the functionality working correctly as you can see in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/x7D3aTOR8vrJ3Z6Menli?p=preview

However I want to filter some data out. To do this, I add a filter like so:

```
ng-repeat-start="(pIndex, x) in pro | filter:{ f: '!B'} | filter:{ f: '!C'}"
```

the plunker with the filter is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xDo5kLsUzIILK4nVyWsa?p=preview

However, this breaks my selection options. If you click on the options in the first plunker and compare to the second plunker you see what I mean. Why did these break? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify this with a few changes.  I forked your [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8Ow4akzqB3mjOb5p9nq?p=preview) so that you can see it in action.

**DemoCtrl**

1.Add scope variables that will contain the selected objects.

```
$scope.selections = {
  parent: {},
  child: {}
};
```

2.Trim down your "get" functions to set these variables.  I may have removed other stuff that was used elsewhere but not pertinent to this question.

```
$scope.getParentDetails = function(parentObj) {
  if (!parentObj.jobs || parentObj.jobs.length === 0) {
    $scope.selections.parent = parentObj;
    $scope.selections.child = {};
  }
};

$scope.getChildDetails = function(childObj) {
  $scope.selections.parent = {};
  $scope.selections.child = childObj;
};
```

**HTML**

Change markup to use the new object variables:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="(pIndex, x) in pro | filter:{ f: '!B'} | filter:{ f: '!C'}" ng-class="{'selected': selections.parent == x}" ng-click="getParentDetails(x)">

<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="job in x.jobs" ng-class="{'selected':selections.child == job}" ng-click="getChildDetails(job)">
```